# How to compare same time in different time zone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have 2 timestamps with different time zones:

```
date_1_str = '20200520090000' # GMT+2
date_2_str = '20 May 2020, 07:00' # UTC
```

I convert them to a `datetime`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

date_1 = datetime.strptime(date_1_str, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S').replace(tzinfo=tz.tzoffset('GMT+2', 0))
date_2 = datetime.strptime(date_2_str, '%d %b %Y, %H:%M').replace(tzinfo=tz.tzoffset('UTC', 0))
```

After that, I convert them to the local time zone to compare:

```py
date_1_ = date_1.astimezone(tz.tzlocal())
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 12, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal())

date_2_ = date_2.astimezone(tz.tzlocal())
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 10, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal())
```

As you can see, it turned out not what I wanted, although in the case of UTC the conversion is correct. After conversion, both objects should be `datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 10, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal())` because my time zone is `gmt+3` so `7.00 utc` == `10.00 gmt+3` and `9.00 gmt+2` must be == `10.00 gmt+3`
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you say "it turned out not what I wanted"? What do you want exactly?

Comment: @seven7e after conversion, both objects should be ```datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 10, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal())``` because my time zone is ```gmt+3``` so ```7.00 utc``` == ```10.00 gmt+3``` and ```9.00 gmt+2``` must be == ```10.00 gmt+3```

Comment: from where do you import `tz`?

Comment: @MrFuppes ```from dateutil import tz```

Comment: @MrFuppes the result is the same ```datetime.strptime(date_1_str, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S').replace(tzinfo=tz.tzoffset('GMT+7200', 0)).astimezone(tz.tzlocal())``` => ```datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 12, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal())```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both [tzoffsets](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.tzoffset) are 0 in your code; if you set them accordingly, you should get the correct output:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

date_1_str = '20200520090000' # GMT+2
date_2_str = '20 May 2020, 07:00' # UTC
date_1 = datetime.strptime(date_1_str, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S').replace(tzinfo=tz.tzoffset('GMT+2', 2*3600))
date_2 = datetime.strptime(date_2_str, '%d %b %Y, %H:%M').replace(tzinfo=tz.tzoffset('UTC', 0))

# I'm on UTC+2, so the hour should stay the same:
date_1_ = date_1.astimezone(tz.tzlocal())
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 9, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal())

# UTC hour should be +2:
date_2_ = date_2.astimezone(tz.tzlocal())
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 9, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal())
```